JsonRequired vs Required Attribute for generating Json Schemas
.NET 8,
Nuget Package JsonSchema.Net.Generation
According to the docs, the [Required] attribute can be used to make a property 'required' when generating a Json Schema from a C# class.
However, for de-serialization using System.Json, one has to use the [JsonRequired] attribute.
I'm lead to the conclusion that to ensure proper deserialization and schema generation, I need to add both attributes.
Is there a way I can tell the SchemaBuilder to look for just [JsonRequired] instead?
I tried executing the following code, but the schema did not mark the property as required.
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;           
using Json.Schema;
using Json.Schema.Generation;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
                var config = new SchemaGeneratorConfiguration();
        config.Nullability = Json.Schema.Generation.Nullability.AllowForNullableValueTypes;
        var schemaBuilder = new JsonSchemaBuilder();
        var schema = schemaBuilder.FromType<Test1>(config).Build();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(schema));
    }
}

public class Test1 
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public int? Test {get;set;} 
    
    public string Test2 {get;set;}
}


You can do it, but required is tricky.  The keyword operates at the object level, but the [JsonRequired] (and [Required]) attribute operates at the property level.  This means that simply adding a handler for the attribute won't work.
My suggestion is to create a refiner that looks for the [JsonRequired] attribute on any of an object's properties and adds a required keyword intent at that point listing all the properties that have the attribute.
There's some additional information as to why I've elected to provide my own [Required] attribute in the nullability docs.  (I might rework some of that in the docs to make it easier to find.)

Alright, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I read the docs and understand the difference between 'nullable' and 'required'.
However, I still do not understand the choice of [Required] over [JsonRequired] in json-everything.
When deserializing using System.Text.Json, [JsonRequired] properties can be NULL but are required. In my mind that means they correspond to JSON schema's required. Why not use the same attribute when serializing to a schema?

In JSON Schema, you can have a property be required and still null.  The concepts are a bit different from each other, and my goal was to capture and support the JSON Schema notion.

I understand. My point: when deserializing, [JsonRequired] properties are required but can still be null. There are no differences in concept there.

TIL.  So, yes that functionality is the same.  The other thing my attribute adds is conditionals.  See https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/schemagen/conditional-generation/#ifminmax-examples

ok, thanks a lot for clarifying!
